# Unable to parse a stringified array containing HTML

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

This may be a silly question but I invested more than half an hour to understand why it is not working. I have a 2D javascript array. Some of the elements in array are HTMl having anchor tag with href attributes.
I am trying to used `JSON.parse("stringified2D array here")` but it give me error as shown in this screenshot.

```
var cd = JSON.parse('[["header","This is some header"],["footer","<p>This addon is brough to you by <a href=\"https://www.accemy.com\">Accemy</a> and <a href=\"swgapps.com\">SW gApps</a></p>This is universal and appended to all add-on content"],["nslookup","NS Lookup allows to fetch DNS records from public DNS servers"]]');
```

It gives me error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 88
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:15
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: that isn't a proper json format

Comment: this is a stringified array. And yes, an array can be be stringified and then parsed. Check here https://imgur.com/PnU1oUB

Comment: Do not generate JSON code manually. Use the language’s built-in functions (e.g. [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP or [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) in JS) or corresponding ready-to-use libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape the quotes twice `\\"`

```
var s = '[' +
  '["header","This is some header"],' +
  '["footer","<p>This addon is brough to you by ' +
  '<a href=\\"https://www.accemy.com\\">Accemy</a> and ' + //here
  '<a href=\\"swgapps.com\\">SW gApps</a></p>' + //and here
  'This is universal and appended to all add-on content"],' +
  '["nslookup","NS Lookup allows to fetch DNS records from public DNS servers"]]';

var cd = JSON.parse(s);

console.log(cd.length); //3
```

Answer (score 3):

You need another `\` to escape double quotes in string:

```
var cd = JSON.parse('[["header","This is some header"],["footer","<p>This addon is brough to you by <a href=\\"https://www.accemy.com\\">Accemy</a> and <a href=\\"swgapps.com\\">SW gApps</a></p>This is universal and appended to all add-on content"],["nslookup","NS Lookup allows to fetch DNS records from public DNS servers"]]');
```